# How to search if a number from a list is present in another list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list that contains some numbers. I have to search those numbers one by one to check if they are present in 2nd list. But I have to check number from 1st list completely i.e if full match is not there, then remove the last digit from the number and search again till match is found. I have to keep doing this for all digits of each number of list 1.

example:

```
z = ['48761', '3876', '481']

p = ['3876112','8935']
```

I pick `3876112`... seach for it in list `z`. if no match, I search `387611`, if no match... I seach for `38761` and so on... Any time in the process if a match is found, I have to return match found and then start doing same for `8935`.

Note: If there is no match at all, I need to return "No match" and that is only Once for that number.

```
z = ['48761', '3876', '481']

p = ['3876112','8935']

for m in range(0,len(p)):
    x = p[m]
    for i in range(0,len(x)):
        y = x
        for words in z:
            if y == words:
                print("Found")      
            x = x[:-1]

    print("Not found")
```

Result:

```
Found
Not found
Not found
```

Also, When I added in between print lines, I noticed with above code, it is running loop one extra time before printing Found.

Comment: When you say "return", do you actually mean "print"?

Comment: I am pretty sure you have an indentation mistake there and this worked by chance because of the input. The line `x = x[:-1]` should be inline with inner-most loop. Meaning should happen once after that loop.

Comment: z and p are actually values from 2 columns.result will be in a new column with found or not found.

Comment: @Tomerikoo When I tried to put x = x[:-1] inline with inner loop, I was not getting any output.

Comment: Weird. Worked for me... Also see what happens when you change the `3876112` to `387612`

Comment: @Tomerikoo Can you please answer the next step of this problem as well. p series was a column in dataframe and against P only I have to add another column with my result. how i can do that? I should have mentioned this in original question but I missed it.

Comment: @VinayPrakash look at my updated answer

Comment: @Tomerikoo thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're working with strings and not actual numbers, you could use [`str.startswith()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith):

```py
z = ['48761', '3876', '481']

p = ['3876112','8935']

res = []
for target in p:
    for num in z:
        if target.startswith(num):
            res.append("Found")
            break   
    else:
        res.append("Not found")
```

Or simply:

```py
res= ["Found" if any(target.startswith(num) for num in z) else "Not Found" for target in p]
```

And now, assuming your dataframe is `df` you can simply do:

```py
df["res"] = res
```

Comment: Awesome! That worked like a charm. :). Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Use slice of string.

```
z = ['48761', '3876', '481']
p = ['3876112','8935']

for p_ in p:
    length = len(p_)
    found = False
    save = None
    for i in range(length):
        if p_[:length-i] in z: 
            found = True
            save = p_[:length-i]
    if found: print('found', save)
    else: print('not found')
```

The result is:

```
found 3876
not found
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked. How i can save the result in a dataframe column against the column p if i want to do that as final result?

Answer (score 1):

Using `str.startswith()` and `any()` to short-circuit early:

```
z = ['48761', '3876', '481']
p = ['3876112','8935']

for num in p:
    if any(num.startswith(n) for n in z):
        print('Found')
    else:
        print('Not Found')
```

Prints:

```
Found
Not Found
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
p = ['3876112','8935']
z = ['48761', '3876', '481']

z = set(z)  # Cast to set for efficient membership search

for elem in p:
    found = False

    for i in reversed(range(1, len(elem))):

        if elem[:i] in z:
            found = True
            print('Found')
            break

    if not found:
        print('Not found')
```

The output is:

```
Found
Not found
```

thus one output line for each input element of the list `p`.